# Images are cut with Slick Slider

Tags: html, jquery, css, carousel, slick.js

Using **adaptiveHeight** option crops the carousel images. Kindly note I need to keep **lazyLoad**.

Is this a bug? I have noticed that after the slide loads, if I resize the window, then the slide image fully shows.

Sample code is available here & down below: https://jsfiddle.net/0fn6hLtd

**html**:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img data-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/560x150"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img data-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/560x65"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img data-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/560"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img data-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/560x200"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**setup**:

```
$('.slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  infinite: true,
  dots:true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

Comment: Try setting the `img` height width attributes so slick can pull values on initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using lazyloader, define `img` height and width attributes so slick can pull values on initialization.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  infinite: true,
  dots:true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 560px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<h2>Slick Slider image is cropped with adaptiveHeight option. Clear cache to see it in action</h2>
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img data-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/560x150" height="150" width="560"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img data-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/560x65" height="65" width="560"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img data-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/560" height="560" width="560" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img data-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/560x200" width="560" height="200" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey coll thanks so much, this should be the correct answer but the only problem is I won't  know the height of any image as they are all dynamic :(

Comment: post-lazyload function trigger slick's resize function? Pass height/width as URL parameters? Set `img src` as smaller, proportionally sized version of image?

Comment: Coll I created a different question specific to this 2nd issue, if you want to participate and thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706746/slick-slider-carousel-how-to-refresh-or-set-current-slide-height-after-that-th