# Slick slider carousel - how to refresh or set current slide height after that the active image loads

Tags: html, jquery, css, carousel, slick.js

I'm using `lazyLoad:ondemand` & since the images have different heights I have to use `adaptiveHeight:true`. But using `adaptiveHeight` + `lazyLoad` trims the images since the Carousel doesn't know each image height & thus can't explicitly set the slides heights.

**In other words**, the carousel doesn't have the height values of the images (& I don't pass them as images attributes as I don't have them) so the slider height doesn't expand.

Here's the setup:

```
$('.slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  infinite: true,
  dots:true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

**Option 1** is to try to resize the active slider after that the image loads. But how?

**Option 2** is to try to set the active slider's height, after that the image has been lazy loaded, but how?

```
$('.slider').on('lazyLoaded', function (e, slick, image, imageSource) {
    //how to get the height of the current image after it has been loaded? Unfortunately image.height() shows 0.
    $('.slick-current',$('.slider')).height(image.height());
});
```

Here's my option 2 try but it's not working (please clear your images cache while testing): https://jsfiddle.net/Lw8kodph